# Example of extracting JSON.decoded data

Tags: json, dart

I am attempting to extract data from a JSON.decode of results from this URL

http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/CarePlan/682734/_history/1?_pretty=true

The parsed data looks like this

```
{
  "resourceType": "CarePlan",
  "id": "682734",
  "meta": {
    "versionId": "1",
    "lastUpdated": "2018-01-12T03:13:38.944-05:00"
  },
  "status": "completed",
  "category": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
          "code": "91251008",
          "display": "Physical therapy procedure"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "subject": {
    "reference": "Patient/682678"
  },
  "context": {
    "reference": "Encounter/682732"
  },
  "period": {
    "start": "2014-01-09",
    "end": "2014-02-04"
  },
  "addresses": [
    {
      "reference": "Condition/682733"
    }
  ],
  "activity": [
    {
      "detail": {
        "code": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
              "code": "229586001",
              "display": "Rest, ice, compression and elevation treatment programme"
            }
          ]
        },
        "status": "completed"
      }
    },
    {
      "detail": {
        "code": {
          "coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
              "code": "229070002",
              "display": "Stretching exercises"
            }
          ]
        },
        "status": "completed"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to extract "code" and "display" at the end of the data

Any example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The result of deconding JSON is a JSON-ish value, either a map or list or a primitive value.
In this case, an example of extracting the values could be:

```dart
var data = JSON.decode(fetchedData);
var code = data["activity"].last["detail"]["code"];
var display = code["coding"][0]["display"];
print(display);  // "Stretching exercises"
```

There is more than one element in the `activity` array, this just accesses the last element (the "code" and "display" at the *end* of the data).

See it [running on DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b451212f949162b866825a3099887fee).